# Mpeg-dash support in nginx

Tags: nginx, mpeg-dash

I searched enough but couldn't sort out how to configure mpeg-dash vod in nginx using nginx_vod_module .

Configuration inside http server block for enabling dash is

```
  location /voddash {
        vod dash;
        vod_mode local;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        gzip on;
        gzip_types application/dash+xml mpd;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin,range,accept-encoding,referer";
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Server,range,Content-Length,Content-Range";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires 100d;
        add_header Last-Modified "Sun, 19 Nov 2000 08:52:00 GMT";
    }
```

Request url is http://localhost/voddash/Input.mp4/manifest.mpd .
I have placed only Input.mp4 in dash location. How can i stream dash content .Also is there anything like streaming of precreated manifest and chunks in nginx for mpeg dash?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration on my server and use the following html + js code to play the dynamically generated manifest.mpd file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dash.js Rocks</title>
        <style>
            video {
                width: 640px;
                height: 360px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <video id="videoPlayer" controls></video>
        </div>
        <script src="http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/nightly/dash.js/dist/dash.all.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function(){
                var url = "http://localhost/voddash/Input.mp4/manifest.mpd";
                var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
                player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```